# Error: “MustUnderstand headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood

Tags: cmis

I am using Alfresco 5.2 and trying to access CMIS RepositoryService, while getting repositories (from .Net client) I am getting below error.

Error: “MustUnderstand headers: [{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood.”

Tried creating custom binding but could not resolve the error as we don't have control on setting 'mustUnderstand' attribute to 0 (zero), I could see the attribute value set to 1 by default and not finding a way to resolve this issue.

Note: There was no such error on Alfresco 5.1.2.

Please let me know whether there is a known bug in Alfresco 5.2 regarding the same?

Also suggest any solution to get it working with Alfresco 5.2.

Rama

below is the soap request

2017-07-05T05:56:33.544Z2017-07-05T06:01:33.544ZadminK0fax@01
--uuid:09b807fc-680b-4cc3-9b4e-63784765a2c5+id=1--

Comment: What binding are you using? WS* perhaps? If so, switch to AtomPub or Browser, they're both miles better!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Using basicHttpBinding with below code
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
same is working for 5.1.2 version but not 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing WS-Security authentication, this is now working.